# Bootstrap 3 - dropdown-toggle - Mudar de menu com ele aberto é possível?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

Com o Bootstrap a tarefa de criar menus para sites ASP.NET fica bem mais simples.

Porém observei que quando um dropdown menu esta "aberto" ao passar o mouse sobre outro item ele não "abre" automaticamente, criando uma certa confusão visual para o usuário, veja na imagem dois menus em destaque mas só um "aberto".

O mouse esta sobre a opção "Cadastros" e a opção "Comandas" esta aberta, só abre a outra opção se clicamos na opção. Vejo em outros sites que quando o menu esta "aberto" ao navegar nas demais opções, que são dowpdown, elas vão sendo apresentadas automaticamente.

É possível ao mover o mouse sobre outra opção, que também seja dropwdown, ela se "abra" automaticamente ?

Grato pela atenção amigos!

[image: vejam a imagem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você consegue realizar isso usando `:hover` no elemento pai `.dropdown` e mudando o display do elemento filho `.dropdown-menu` para `block`.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```css
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {  display: block;}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">        
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"
  integrity="sha256-fNXJFIlca05BIO2Y5zh1xrShK3ME+/lYZ0j+ChxX2DA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Jorge Matheus, obrigado pela ajuda. O seu BootStrap é de versão mais atual, o que eu uso é 3.3.7, estou tentando mas não deu resultado.
Acredito que só atualizando o bootstrap, o que não posso nem pensar em fazer, desmontaria todo layout do site.

Comment: @AriVenuth coloquei a versão que estás a usar, mas a solução continua a mesma. Dê uma olhada.

Comment: PERFEITO!!! Só precisei colocar class dropdown nas tags <li> do meu html, muito obrigado !!!

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue usando os eventos `mouseenter` e `mouseleave`, disparando um `click` manual no botão (veja comentários no código). Desta forma o dropdown irá se abrir apenas ao passar o mouse (evento `mouseenter`) e se fechar ao tirar (evento `mouseleave`).

Execute o exemplo em tela cheia:

```js
$(".dropdown-toggle").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e){
   
   // só irá usar os eventos se o menu hamburguer estiver oculto
   if(!$(".navbar-toggle").is(":visible")){
      if(e.type == "mouseenter"){
         $(this)
         .attr("aria-expanded", "true")
         .closest(".dropdown")
         .addClass("open"); // adiciona a classe que abre o menu
      }
      if(e.type == "mouseleave"){
         var $t = $(this);
         setTimeout(function(){ // este pequeno delay é para não piscar
            $t
            .attr("aria-expanded", "false")
            .closest(".dropdown")
            .removeClass("open"); // remove a classe que abre o menu
         }, 100);
      }
   }
});

// se sair do menu, dispara o click no botão e esconde
$(".dropdown-menu").on("mouseleave", function(){
   if(!$(".navbar-toggle").is(":visible")){
      $(this)
      .closest(".dropdown")
      .find(".dropdown-toggle")
      .trigger("click");
   }
});
```

```css
.bs-example{
   margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="bs-example">
    <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Admin <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: a solução do Jorge Matheus resolveu perfeitamente, mais tarde vou usar a sua solução em outro site que estou editando, muito obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Blz meu jovem. Espero que ajude.